# JS: how to shift each letter in the given string N places down in the alphabet?

Tags: javascript, string

how to shift each letter in the given string N places down in the alphabet? Punctuation, spaces, and capitalization should remain intact. For example if the string is "ac" and num is 2 the output should be "ce". What's wrong with my code? It converts letter to ASCII and adds given number then converts from ASCII to letter back. The last line replaces space.

```
function CaesarCipher(str, num) {

    str = str.toLowerCase();
    var result = '';
    var charcode = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        charcode = (str[i].charCodeAt()) + num;
        result += (charcode).fromCharCode();
    }
    return result.replace(charcode.fromCharCode(), ' ');

}
```

I'm getting

```
TypeError: charcode.fromCharCode is not a function
```

Comment: `charcode` is a Number, and a number does not have the function `fromCharCode`, you are looking for:  [String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

Comment: your usage is not correct.  String.fromCharCode is a method that converts a unicode number to string.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromCharCode.asp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to pass an argument to the fromCharCode method using the String object. Try:

```js
function CaesarCipher(str, num) {
    // you can comment this line
    str = str.toLowerCase();

    var result = '';
    var charcode = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        charcode = (str[i].charCodeAt()) + num;
        result += String.fromCharCode(charcode);
    }
    return result;

}
console.log(CaesarCipher('test', 2));
```

I had to modify the return statement, because it was introducing a bug for me

Comment: While this code solves the immediate problem from the question, it does not "keep spaces, punctuation, etc. intact". This should be mentioned in the answer, since it is being linked from other questions.

Comment: This also doesn't handle the case where you already have Z, and need to shift this 2 to the right and should then get to B.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem at all I'm afraid.

Comment: its not going to solve the problem. try console.log(CaesarCipher('test', 28)); it returns non ascii characters.

Answer (score 4):

One need to take into account fact of shifting last letters in alphabet back to beginning. Here is my take on that:

```js
var input = "Caesar Cipher";
    
function CaesarCipher(str, num) {
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var newStr = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var char = str[i],
            isUpper = char === char.toUpperCase() ? true : false;

        char = char.toLowerCase();

        if (alphabet.indexOf(char) > -1) {
            var newIndex = alphabet.indexOf(char) + num;
            if(newIndex < alphabet.length) {
              isUpper ? newStr += alphabet[newIndex].toUpperCase() : newStr += alphabet[newIndex];
            } else {
              var shiftedIndex = -(alphabet.length - newIndex);
                isUpper ? newStr += alphabet[shiftedIndex].toUpperCase() : newStr += alphabet[shiftedIndex];
            }
        } else {
           newStr += char;
        }
    }
    return newStr;
}

console.log(CaesarCipher(input, 20));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hedgehog34/g1zcpfjy/)

Answer (score 3):

```
function caesarCipher(s, k) {
    var n = 26; // alphabet letters amount
    if (k < 0) {
        return caesarCipher(s, k + n);
    }
    return s.split('')
        .map(function (c) {
            if (c.match(/[a-z]/i)) {
                var code = c.charCodeAt();
                var shift = code >= 65 && code <= 90 ? 65 : code >= 97 && code <= 122 ? 97 : 0;
                return String.fromCharCode(((code - shift + k) % n) + shift);
            }
            return c;
        }).join('');
}
```

Use String.charCodeAt() to convert the English character to ASCII.

Use String.fromCharCode() to convert ASCII to English character.

Try `caesarCipher("always-look-on-the-bright-side-of-life", 10)` => "kvgkic-vyyu-yx-dro-lbsqrd-csno-yp-vspo"

`caesarCipher("kvgkic-vyyu-yx-dro-lbsqrd-csno-yp-vspo", -10)` => "always-look-on-the-bright-side-of-life"

Answer (score 3):

Tossing my hat into the fray here, as I just completed this [same challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/caesar-cipher-1/problem) over on HackerRank.

My solution is similar to the one proposed by @Alexa-905.

#### Objectives:

- Rotate the alphabet by `k`, e.g., `k = 3`, `a` becomes `d`, `z` becomes `c`
- Uppercase letters stay uppercase, same for lowercase
- All other non `[a-zA-Z]` characters remain the same

#### Magic Numbers Explained:

- `65-90` are the ranges for `A-Z` (uppercase letters)
- `97-122` are the ranges for `a-z` (lowercase letters)
- `26` is the number of letters in the alphabet

#### Solution:

```js
function caesarCipher(s, k) {
    let result = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        const charCode = s.charCodeAt(i);

        if (
            (charCode < 65 || charCode > 122) ||
            (charCode > 90 && charCode < 97)
        ) {
            result += s[i];
        } else {
            let newCharCode = charCode + Math.ceil(k % 26);

            if (charCode >= 97 && newCharCode > 122) {
                newCharCode = newCharCode - 122 + 96;
            }
            if (charCode <= 90 && newCharCode > 90) {
                newCharCode = newCharCode - 90 + 64;
            }

            result += String.fromCharCode(newCharCode);
        }

    }

    console.log(result);
    return result
}

caesarCipher('F rpb Jxqe.zbfi(h%26) ql zrq altk lk olqxqflkp', 3);
caesarCipher('26 rb cqn wdvkna xo unccnab rw cqn juyqjknc', 17)
caesarCipher('65-90 mdq ftq dmzsqe rad M-L (gbbqdomeq xqffqde)', 534);
caesarCipher('97-122 kbo dro bkxqoc pyb k-j (vygobmkco voddobc)', 425974);
caesarCipher('Aopz jvkl ybuz ha 454,064 vwlyhapvuz wly zljvuk!', 19);
caesarCipher('myyux://oxujwk.htr/hfjxfw-nk-ax-wjljc/1', 141235435141);
```

Answer (score 1):

The fromCharCode function doesn't operate on strings, it operates on the global `String` object like so `String.fromCharCode(65, 66, 67);  // "ABC"` ripped off straight from the docs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode

Answer (score 1):

That's my solution

```js
function rot13(str) {
  var result = str.split("")
                  .map(function(val) {
                    var letterKey = val.charCodeAt() - 13;
                    if(letterKey < 65){
                      letterKey = 90 - (65 - letterKey - 1);
                    }
                    console.log(letterKey);
                    return String.fromCharCode(letterKey);
                  })
                  .join("");
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old but I thought I'd give it a go. Here's my take on it.

It accounts for uppercase and lowercase. It can also shift either forwards or backwards any amount!

```js
function shift(str, n) {
 var shifted = '';
 n = n%26;
 for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  let code = str[i].charCodeAt();
    let capital = (code > 64 && code < 91) ? true : false;
    if (code < (capital?65:97) || code > (capital?90:122) || n == 0) {
      shifted += str[i];
      continue;
    }
    if (n > 0) {
      if (code > (capital?90:122)-n) {
     code = n + code - 26;
    } else {
     code += n;
    }
    } else {
      if (code < (capital?65:97)-n) {
     code = code + n + 26;
    } else {
     code += n;
    }
    }
  shifted += String.fromCharCode(code);
 }
 return shifted;
}

console.log(shift('Ebiil, Tloia!', 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
result += String.fromCharCode(charcode)
```

*Taken from: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromCharCode.asp*

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving it as below.

Note: This includes rolling of small, capital and Numeric characters. special symbols renders as it is.

```js
 function rotationalCipher(input, rotationFactor) {
      // Write your code here
      if (!input || rotationFactor < 0 || rotationFactor > 1000000) {
        return "";
      }

      let capitalLetters = [...Array(26).keys()].map((n) => n + 65);
      let smallLetters = [...Array(26).keys()].map((n) => n + 97);
      let numerics = [...Array(10).keys()].map((n) => n + 48);

      return input
        .split("")
        .map((char) => {
          let asciiCode = char.charCodeAt();

          if (asciiCode >= 97 && asciiCode <= 122) {
            let newAsciiCode = smallLetters.indexOf(asciiCode) + rotationFactor;
            return String.fromCharCode(smallLetters[Math.round(newAsciiCode % 26)]);
          } else if (asciiCode >= 65 && asciiCode <= 90) {
            let newAsciiCode = capitalLetters.indexOf(asciiCode) + rotationFactor;
            return String.fromCharCode(
              capitalLetters[Math.round(newAsciiCode % 26)]
            );
          } else if (asciiCode >= 48 && asciiCode <= 57) {
            let newAsciiCode = numerics.indexOf(asciiCode) + rotationFactor;
            return String.fromCharCode(numerics[Math.round(newAsciiCode % 10)]);
          } else {
            return char;
          }
        })
        .join("");
    }

    console.log(rotationalCipher("bB_1c", 10));
    console.log(rotationalCipher("bB_1c", 100));
    console.log(rotationalCipher("bB_1c", 9));
    console.log(rotationalCipher("bB_1cbB_1cbB_1cbB_1cbB_1c", 900));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for me is below:
(Code in JavaScript)

```
function caesarCipherEncryptor(string, key) {
    let output = "";
    for(let char of string){
        let newCode = char.charCodeAt() + key % 26;
        if(newCode <= 122){
                output += String.fromCharCode(newCode);
        } else {
            output += String.fromCharCode(96 + (newCode%122));
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```