# Making secret language useing charAt

Tags: javascript, charat

I need to make a textbox with in there a word when i click on a button that word needs to convert into numbers useing charAt and that number needs to get +2 and than converted back into words and that word needs to get alerted i dont know what to do i find this really hard i made a function that is useless but i just want to show you what i did please help :)

```
    function codeer(){

        var woord2 = document.getElementById("woord")
        var woordterug = woord2.charAt(0)
        var woord234 = document.getElementById("woord");
        var woord23 = woord234.charAt(str.length+2);

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33085029/1743938

Answer (score 1):

You could get the char code with [`String#charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) from the character add two and build a new string with [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).

```js
function codeer() {
    var woord = document.getElementById("woord").value,
        coded = '',
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < woord.length; i++) {
        coded += String.fromCharCode(woord.charCodeAt(i) + 2);
    }
    console.log(coded);
}
```

```html
<input id="woord" /> <button onclick="codeer()">cooder</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should search the internet for a JavaScript rot13 example. In that code, you just need to replace the 13 with a 2, and it should work.