# Javascript - Shift characters of a string from n places

Tags: javascript, string

The problem is for given string I have to shift each letter from given number places.

For example,

```
Encrypt(‘ABC’, 4) should return "EFG"
Encrypt("AB C", 2) Should equal to “CD E”
Encrypt("ABC DEF", 2) Should equal to “CDE FGH”
```

This is the solution I have come up with;

```
function encrypt(str, index) {
    var encryptedstr = '';
    var charCode = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);

        if (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 77 ){
            encryptedstr += String.fromCharCode(charCode + index);
        }else{
            encryptedstr += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        }
    }
    return encryptedstr;
}
```

This works fine for given inputs. But it keeps telling me that "*The answer should be valid for any given input.*" What did I do wrong here?

I change the code as following, but it also gives me the same error.

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) 
{
    if(str[i] === " ")
    {
        encryptedstr += " ";  
    }else{
        charCode = (str[i].charCodeAt()) + index;
        encryptedstr += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    }        
}
```

Comment: are you given any information about the kinds of inputs you should be able to deal with? What about lower-case characters?

Comment: *"But it keeps telling me"* Who or what is *it*? And for which input does it fail?

Comment: You probably need to shift `Z` to `D`, for example.

Comment: @Hamms The input string will always be in uppercase.

Comment: Charcode of `Z` isn't 77.

Comment: Is your code working? I am trying that out it returning the same value

Comment: @FelixKling I'm doing this as challenge. They don't tell for which input this fails. Sorry.

Comment: @Ashishsah yes it work for given input except that error.

Comment: What are the input constrains of the problem ? @Hamms is correct saying that you need to know these. If you have a comma in the sentence, that's enough to break your code e.g.

Comment: Also worth considering the range of valid inputs for the `index` argument; negative values or those greater than 26 will also cause problems

Comment: *Please* don't call this function "encrypt". That's not what it's doing. Call it `encode`.

Comment: @Bergi That just the name they have called it. I can't change it.

Comment: @Niloct I haven't covered all the constraints. That's why this won't work. I add those constraint and now it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: @Hamms I have missed one constrain. That's why it didn't work. I didn't cover non-alpha characters constraint. Now it works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I haven't cover all constraint. That's why it didn't works. I have to consider non-alpha characters also. I have found the solution to this in different post.

[If you have same problem go to this link and follow the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33948669/5278402)